# Changing Django's model attribute value

Tags: python, django, database, web

in models.py

```
class Auction(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

in views.py

```
def Listing(request,Person_id):
    Per=Person.objects.get(pk=Person_id)
    if request.method=="POST":
        Per.name=(request.POST["Rename"]).cleaned_data
        Per.save()
    return render(request,"Projectapp/Person.html",{"Person":Person.objects.get(pk=Person_id)})
```

but then when checking Per.name it returns the old name. I want to ask how to change an attribute's value of django model after object creation

Comment: You did not make a POST request, since a POST request would error on the `.cleaned_data`.

Comment: oh thanks a lot I really found a wrong syntax in Preson.html form I wrote <form method="-post" unintentionally . I removed cleaned_data and it works now